# Trying to compare target sales vs actual sales

Tags: sql, sql-server, kaggle, portfolio

Hello I have a dataset from kaggle that I am using for a beginner level portfolio. I am stuck on a part that does not seem that complicated so I hoping one of you guys could help me out.

So what I just finished doing is making a query to return the monthly totals and profits by month and year with the following code:

```
Select Year(list.OrderDateFixed) as Year, Month(list.OrderDateFixed) as Month, Sum(od.Amount) as TotalAmount, sum(od.profit) as TotalProfit
from [List of Orders] list
    join [Order Details] od
    on list.[Order ID] = od.[Order ID]
Group by  YEAR(list.OrderDateFixed), MONTH(list.OrderDateFixed)
Order by  YEAR(list.OrderDateFixed), MONTH(list.OrderDateFixed)
```

It returns the following:

```
Year    Month   TotalAmount TotalProfit
2018    4   32726.00    -3960.00
2018    5   28545.00    -3584.00
2018    6   23658.00    -4970.00
2018    7   12966.00    -2138.00
2018    8   30899.00    -2180.00
2018    9   26628.00    -4963.00
2018    10  31615.00    3093.00
2018    11  48086.00    11619.00
2018    12  37579.00    5284.00
2019    1   61439.00    9760.00
2019    2   38424.00    5917.00
2019    3   58937.00    10077.00
```

I am trying to output something like that with the sales target of the month to the column on the right.
The sales target table looks like this with all the categories:

```
MonthOrderDateFixed Category    Target
2018-04-01  Furniture   10400.00
2018-05-01  Furniture   10500.00
2018-06-01  Furniture   10600.00
2018-07-01  Furniture   10800.00
2018-08-01  Furniture   10900.00
2018-09-01  Furniture   11000.00
2018-10-01  Furniture   11100.00
2018-11-01  Furniture   11300.00
................................
```

So I was thinking maybe I could use a cte from the first query and then join the sales target table, but I am not sure how to join it when the dates are divided up into separate columns. Also, I attempted to make a temp table but I think I ran into the same problem with the date formats.

I am hoping to be able to easily compare the targets with the actual amounts so then I could do something like finding the differences. If someone can help guide me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/benroshan/ecommerce-data

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to extract the year and month from a date (it's also possible to connect the dates from the other table and you can present which info you want).

```
select *
from   t full join t2 on  year(MonthOrderDateFixed)  = t.Year
                      and month(MonthOrderDateFixed) = t.Month
```

| Year | Month | TotalAmount | TotalProfit | MonthOrderDateFixed | Category | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 4 | 32726 | -3960 | 2018-04-01 00:00:00.000 | Furniture | 10400 |
| 2018 | 5 | 28545 | -3584 | 2018-05-01 00:00:00.000 | Furniture | 10500 |
| 2018 | 6 | 23658 | -4970 | 2018-06-01 00:00:00.000 | Furniture | 10600 |
| 2018 | 7 | 12966 | -2138 | 2018-07-01 00:00:00.000 | Furniture | 10800 |
| 2018 | 8 | 30899 | -2180 | 2018-08-01 00:00:00.000 | Furniture | 10900 |
| 2018 | 9 | 26628 | -4963 | 2018-09-01 00:00:00.000 | Furniture | 11000 |
| 2018 | 10 | 31615 | 3093 | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | Furniture | 11100 |
| 2018 | 11 | 48086 | 11619 | 2018-11-01 00:00:00.000 | Furniture | 11300 |
| 2018 | 12 | 37579 | 5284 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2019 | 1 | 61439 | 9760 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2019 | 2 | 38424 | 5917 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2019 | 3 | 58937 | 10077 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=28ce797b86b062f3ba9d6f58ee81d6bc&hide=1)

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple

Comment: Actually when I do this, it keeps outputting like this where it is saying the total for each category is the same. Any suggestions?


Year Month Category TotalAmount TotalProfit
2018 4 Furniture 32726.00 -3960.00
2018 4 Clothing 32726.00 -3960.00
2018 4 Electronics 32726.00 -3960.00
2018 5 Electronics 28545.00 -3584.00
2018 5 Clothing 28545.00 -3584.00
2018 5 Furniture 28545.00 -3584.00

Comment: I just connected them in a way where the dates match. It's going to give you all the options that apply. You need to add more stipulations to it (I need to see it, but probably something with the Category).